# How to query project notes on Github using GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-projects

I found a project at the address https://github.com/delbaoliveira/website/projects/1. I am using the [GitHub GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) to retrieve the desired notes.
[image]
I also created a similar project, but the returned result is undefined. I suspect that the variable columnId is incorrect.

[image]

So, how can I obtain the `columnId`? Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `columnId` with this query:

```
query { 
  repository(name: "website", owner: "delbaoliveira") {
    project(number: 1) {
      name
      columns(first: 1) {
        nodes {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But also you can go ahead and get column data without `columnId` like this:

```
query { 
  repository(name: "website", owner: "delbaoliveira") {
    project(number: 1) {
      name
      columns(first: 1) {
        nodes {
          name
          cards {
            nodes {
              note
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```